# How to canonicalize SMILES written with aromatic bond symbols (:)?

Tags: rdkit, smiles, openbabel

I am using a package called PySmiles and it is returning a dialect of SMILES for aromatic groups that uses aromatic bond symbols
e.g.
`NC:1:N:N:C:[N]1N`.

RDKit does not recognize these symbols  and it removes all the aromaticity.

Interestingly, Openbabel Version 2.3.2 successfully canonicalizes this to `Nc1nncn1N` but version 3.1.0 produces `NC1NNCN1N` similar to what RDKit produces.

[I've opened an issue on the Github Openbabel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/issues/2368) to address this issue but I'd like to ask it here (i.e. why does do versions 2.3.2 and 3.1.0 in OpenBabel give different results?) since this might be a general issue related to SMILES dialects.

Comment: This looks like SMARTS, not SMILES. In RDKit, `Chem.MolFromSmarts('NC:1:N:N:C:[N]1N')` looks like it loads it correctly. You can see the `:` character and other definitions on https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smarts.html

Answer (score 8):

**tldr; That SMILES is invalid**

This was [answered on GitHub](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/issues/2368#issuecomment-843053926) by Noel O'Boyle, but I wanted to provide more context.

First off, versions:

- I had to go back and check, but Open Babel 2.3.2 was released in [October 2012](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/releases/tag/openbabel-2-3-2)
- [Version 3.0 and later](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ReleaseNotes/ob300.html) implement the Daylight SMILES aromaticity model and have a thoroughly rewritten SMILES code (by Noel).

So why do the different versions give different results? Because 2.3.2 has a very forgiving aromaticity model and it's wrong.

In particular, as noted by Noel, SMILES defines aromaticity through atoms:

> Atom aromaticity in SMILES is determined by the case of the characters, not
> by the nature of the attached bonds.

Since the characters are in caps, SMILES indicates they are non-aromatic atoms.

But let's not limit ourselves to Open Babel and RDKit. I tried that SMILES in ChemDraw:

[image]

I also tried your SMILES with the [NIH resolver](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure), which runs CACTVS [here](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/NC%3A1%3AN%3AN%3AC%3A%5BN%5D1N/gif). It returns a 404 error, in essence the SMILES is invalid.

I don't know your project, but if you want to use SMILES, you should use a full toolkit like RDKit, Open Babel, or Open Eye -- they have years of testing.

And depending on your needs, [SELFIES](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/5006/30) might work. I don't remember if it includes all features in SMILES yet, but it's designed for robust ML and has proven utility in a number of recent papers.

Answer (score 7):

I think it might be good to have a look at SELFIES by Alan Aspuru-Guzik and co-workers: https://github.com/aspuru-guzik-group/selfies
From what I remember from his talk in Girona last December, this should do better than SMILES for many systems, which you can also infer from the title of the corresponding paper: "Self-Referencing Embedded Strings (SELFIES): A 100% robust molecular string representation".